# PHP Date String convert into integer or numeric

Tags: php, date, datetime

Currently, I have date from my database every time I start the session the date format looks like this: `2022-09-26 05:19:34`

In order for the date format to become friendly on the front end or client side, I use this function:

`date("F j, Y", strtotime( $fetchDate ));` The generate output look like this: `September 26, 2022`

Then, however, I need to filter the session in admin by **"Date"** the format from the client side is not the same as the date format in my database, right?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByXXn.png)

To makes long story short how can I convert my string Date format into the default database format that I can use when I filter by **"Date"** in my database

```
// Here is the example of a filter I need to do
SELECT * FROM `start_session` WHERE `Date_created` = '2022-09-26 05:19:34'
```

```
// However as you can see I have this kind of wrong
SELECT * FROM `start_session` WHERE `Date_created` = 'September 26, 2022'
```

If I can convert this date `2022-09-26 05:19:34` into this format `September 26, 2022` using this function `date("F j, Y", strtotime( $fetchDate ))`

How can I convert this date format `September 26, 2022` to become like this format `2022-09-26 05:19:34`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the PHP you are using to make the call

Comment: You can have a look at the PHP date formats: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php , what you need is: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` is remarkably versatile. You can use this

```php
$dbmsdate = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'September 26, 2022' ) );
```

to get that date. But, of course you cannot get the time `05:19:34` from that date string because no information about the time is in it.